# CodeIgniter - Query going wrong somewhere

Tags: codeigniter

In my model i have the following code:

```
        $this->db->from($this->table_name);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $userid);
    $this->db->where('role_key', $key);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Then in my view i have the following

```
$ci =& get_instance();
```

$thistest = $ci->model->functionname($row->id,$role->key);

if($thistest > 0){
    echo 'valid';
}

I know im not meant to be calling stuff from a view, im just running a test, but its not working, and im cant seem to figure out why .... its just echoing valid a whole bunch of times when according to the database, its only meant to echo it twice.

Comment: do a `print_r($query->result());` in your model and then `exit` and see what's acutally being returned. also what's `functionname` do ? and why bother with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do but I'm pretty sure that this code won't work. if what you are trying is return some data from your a table you can do something like that...

```
$query = $this->db->get('entries');  //so here you get data from the table called entries

    $entries = array();  //here you create an array called entries(I use the same name                                     //because it's more or less the same data)


//here is where we retrieve all data and insert them in the array we previously created
//if we don't want some data from our table we can omit them...
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $entry) {
      $entries[] = array('title' => $entry['title'],
          'body' => $entry['body'],
          'author' => $entry['author'],
          'date_time' => $entry['date_time'],
          'id' => $entry['id']
      );
    }

    return $entries;   //finally we return the array
```

now you can call this array somewhere in your controller and load it in a view...in the code you displayed several queries was displayed without any actual connection with each other and finally you return something called `$this->db->get();` without  including any table name into it...
use that as reference and good luck
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html